# How to group posts by category using PHP & MySql?

Tags: php, mysql

I’ve tried using GROUP BY in my query but that only returns one post per category. This is an example of what is returned with my current setup. What I need is for all posts with the same category to be grouped together, can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Use PHP to group them each categorie separate into a variable (an array, finished html rendering) and then print these variables at the right position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like suggested by Charlotte, you could group your posts in an associative array, with the categories as keys.

```
<?php

// Connecting to database

$categories = array(); // Create an empty array
while ($post = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if(!array_key_exists($post['category'], $categories)) { // Check if the category is already present
        $categories[$post['category']] = array(); // Create an array indexed with the category name
    }
    $categories[$post['category']][] = $post; // Add the post to the category
}
?>
```

Now you have to iterate twice : to display the categories and to display each post in the category.
When I have to deal with nested `foreach` to render html, I preferably use [inline foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).

The rendering of the posts should look like :

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $category => $posts) : ?>
    <h2><?php echo $category; ?></h2>
    <?php foreach ($posts as $post) : ?>
        <a href='article.php?id=<?php echo $post['post_id']; ?>' ><?php echo $post['title']; ?></a>
        <p>Posted on <?php echo date('d-m-y h:i:s',strtotime( $post['posted'] ) );?> In <a href='category5.php?id=<?php echo $post['category_id']; ?>' ><?php echo $post['category']; ?></a>
        </p>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <hr/>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Edit: I ometted the opening and closing php tags in the first block of code.
If you assemble the two blocks of code in your php file, it should work.

Comment: Thank you Lex & Charlotte this is exactly what I however when I add the code above there seems to be a mix between html and PHP. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'

Comment: Scratch that I was missing a closing ?> thank you very much this has cracked it for me!